# Protect Excel Worksheet with multiple protection variables

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

Using Excel VBA, how do I lock worksheets with multiple different variables i.e. Allowing users to use Autofilter and the sort option.

I have gotten this far:

Worksheets("Sheet 1").Protect Password:="Password"

What do I write next to allow user to:
Select un/locked cells
Format columns/rows
Sort
Use Autofilter

Thank you,

Comment: Unprotect it I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 16 parameters you can use with the `Protect` method of the worksheet. Here is a code sample based off this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) article:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LockSheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    ws.Protect Password:="Foo", _
        DrawingObjects:=True, _
        Contents:=True, _
        Scenarios:=True, _
        UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
        AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
        AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
        AllowInsertingColumns:=True, _
        AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
        AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
        AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, _
        AllowSorting:=True, _
        AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer given by @Robin, here is the URL to the .Protect function, you may find it usefull to read what each of the parameters do, also some are assumed to be true and some to be false.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx

Kind regards,

lewisthegruffalo

Comment: Thanks Lewis! Robin already mentioned this link; but after you mentioned it I had a another look and found more useful information I will be using. Thanks again!